# Get only max value although where = not max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I will get only max value although where = not value MAX,
This is my table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       JAMINAN       |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       20210101      |      A0317010    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       20200101      |      A0317010    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and this is my code to get MAX value

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(12),a.akhir_jaminan,112)) AS ID,  
    a.kode_aparat AS ID
FROM mps_ms_history_jaminan_aparat a 
WHERE a.kode_aparat = 'A0317010'
GROUP BY a.kode_aparat
```

This is result:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       JAMINAN       |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       20210101      |      A0317010    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I will if function WHERE akhir_jaminan = not max, result NULL data...this is my code:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(12),a.akhir_jaminan,112)) AS jaminan,  
    a.kode_aparat AS id
FROM mps_ms_history_jaminan_aparat a 
WHERE a.kode_aparat = 'A0317010' AND CONVERT(CHAR(6),a.akhir_jaminan,112) = '202001' 
GROUP BY a.kode_aparat
```

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       JAMINAN       |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       20200101      |      A0317010    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I will get result like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       JAMINAN       |         ID       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       NULL          |      NULL        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: ok, I use SQL server

Comment: So which query doesn't give you the desired result? Both queries seem to work fine:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=0cef6b93b71b3d2c87434d258f53e84f

Comment: Click on the DB Fiddle link in my previous comment, the second query also returns the correct result.

Comment: I will get  `if where = '202001'` result null data, just show max data

Comment: Can you edit this fiddle and show us how you get `null` data? pls paste the link to the new fiddle here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=0cef6b93b71b3d2c87434d258f53e84f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, what you want is to display the latest date, if it is not the latest date it will display null to the user.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(12),a.akhir_jaminan,112)) = '20200101'
    THEN a.akhir_jaminan ELSE NULL END AS jaminan,
    CASE WHEN a.kode_aparat = 'A0317010' 
    THEN a.kode_aparat ELSE null END AS id
FROM mps_ms_history_jaminan_aparat a
GROUP BY a.akhir_jaminan, a.kode_aparat
```

This is using **CASE** clause to let the script able to determine whether the latest date is the desired date.
If it is not the desired script, you might comment below and I will amend the script asap.